# Call the cropped image of a custom field in the theme

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, images

I use Wordpress as a CMS. I have created my own theme. To manage the content I use 'Advanced Custom Fields'. With the plugin 'Simple Image Sizes' I created a custom image size. The preview gets croped like I want it but if I call the picture in the theme like that

```
<img src="<?php echo get_field("aktuell_titel"); ?>">
```

the original image gets displayed.
How do I make sure that the cropped image is displayed in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Set the return setting for your ACF field to "Image ID" (instead of "Image URL"). Then in your code:

```
<?php

if ( $image_id = get_field( 'aktuell_titel' ) )
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'name_of_custom_size' );
```